# Use PHP to connect to odbc datasource in different directory

Tags: php, odbc, database-connection

I have a simple PHP script that connects to an Access .mdb like this:

```
$connection = odbc_connect('cmis008f','nousername','nopassword');
```

Both the cmis008f.mdb and the file.php are in the same directory /odbc; however, I want to move the file.php into the /PHP directory but cannot connect any longer, even if I do this:

```
$connection = odbc_connect('\cmis057s\odbc\cmis008f','nousername','nopassword');
```

I even flipped the slashes and tried that way... no luck. Any suggestions. 
/odbc and /PHP are both under the same directory /cmis057s.

Thanks

Comment: You can bypass access security by holding down shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try any or all of this:

1. Use normal slash ( `/` )
2. Try to use "../" (parent directory) instead of full path
3. Check chmod (permissions) of directories